# Porcentagem com if em Python

Tags: python, if, porcentagem

Olá, sou iniciante em Python e me deparei com uma grande dúvida numa lição que estou fazendo. Estou fazendo um programa que pega as informações do usuário como:nome, data de nascimento, cargo e salario. Após isto ele define um limite de gasto conforme o salario e idade do usuário.

Meu próximo exercício é para solicitar que o usuário digite o valor de um produto, e se o valor estiver abaixo de 60% do limite, mandar uma msg, entre 60% e 90% outra msg e entre 90% e 100%, outra msg.

Minha dúvida é, como calcular estas porcentagens dentro de um if em python?

Não vou citar meu código aqui pois talvez receberia a resposta de mão beijada... so gostaria de um auxílio nesta questão de if com porcentagem. Obrigado!!!

Comment: "*Não vou citar meu código aqui pois talvez receberia a resposta de mão beijada*" - Na verdade é o contrário: quando você não coloca nenhum código, **passa a impressão** de que não fez nada e quer que façamos tudo pra vc (mesmo que não seja isso, é a impressão que passa). O ideal é colocar o que já tentou e explicar porque não funcionou - que é o que chamamos de [mcve]

Comment: ah... beleza não sabia. É que é para um exercício da faculdade e não queria ter uma resposta com todos os cálculos ja feitos e etc... mas ja fiz todo o restante do código sim, só faltou este cálculo. Obrigado por esclarecer, irei melhorar nas próximas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas para complementar a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469912/112052):

No `elif` não precisa testar se `PRODUTO >= LIMITE * 0.6`.
Se não entrou no `if PRODUTO < LIMITE * 0.60`, é porque o produto não é menor que `LIMITE * 0.60`. Então se chegou no `elif` é porque ele é certamente maior ou igual. Então bastaria testar a outra condição:

```
limite = 1000
produto = 901

if produto < limite * 0.6:
    print('valor menor que 60%')
elif produto <= limite * 0.9:
    print('entre 60% e 90')
elif produto <= limite:
    print('entre 90% e 100%')
```

Ou seja, se for menor que 60%, entra no `if`.

Se não entrou no `if`, é porque é maior ou igual a 60%. Então no `elif` basta testar se é menor ou igual a 90%. Testar novamente se é `>= limite * 0.6` é redundante e desnecessário.

Também incluí um teste para ver se está entre 90% e 100%, que parece ser um requisito. Não ficou definido o que fazer se o valor for maior que 100% do limite, nem se for negativo, mas se fosse o caso, bastaria adicionar novas condições. Ex:

```
if produto < 0:
    print('valor não pode ser negativo')
elif produto < limite * 0.6:
    print('valor menor que 60%')
elif produto <= limite * 0.9:
    print('entre 60% e 90')
elif produto <= limite:
    print('entre 90% e 100%')
else:
    print('valor maior que o limite')
```

A ideia é a mesma: se for menor que zero entra no `if`. Se não entrar ali, é porque com certeza é maior ou igual a zero, então no primeiro `elif` eu só testo se é menor que 60%. E por aí vai...

Repare também que escrevi os números como `0.6` e `0.9`. Como são [literais numéricos](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating), os zeros a mais (`0.60` e `0.90`) não fazem diferença.

E usei os nomes de variáveis com letras minúsculas, seguindo as [convenções da PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).

Answer (score 1):

Teoricamente para calcular a porcentagem de um determinado `valor`, basta dividi-lo por 100 e multiplica-lo pelo `numero` que você quer, ou simplesmente, multiplicar o `valor` pela `taxa`, onde a taxa será sempre `0,x`.

por exemplo, quero saber 50% de 2000 quanto da:
(2000 / 100) * 50
ou ainda 2000 * 0,50

75% de 325
(325/100) * 75
ou 325 * 0,75

```
LIMITE=1000
PRODUTO=901

if PRODUTO < LIMITE * 0.60 :
    print('valor menor que 60%')
elif PRODUTO >= LIMITE * 0.60 and PRODUTO <= LIMITE * 0.90:
    print('entre 60% e 90')
else:
    print('maior que 90%')
    
abs!
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcus!! Ajudou muito, era mais simples do que imaginava... rs